# Copy each string from a 2D array into a 1D array

Tags: c, string

I want to grab each string in a 2D array and concatenate that to a separate 1D string array. i have been able to take each string from a 2D array but I couldn't quite concatenate that with the 1D array.

If Dimen2 is the 2D array that contains strings "apple,orange,grapes"

I want to obtain a 1D array Dimen1 which contains "appleorangegrapes"

I want to do this in C.

Comment: What is your problem? Read a tutorial, try it, and come back when you have a clear question.

Comment: Three standard functions spring to my mind: `strcat()`, `strcpy()`, and `asprintf()`. If you can, use the later as the other two can easily overrun the buffers you pass to them. Just read their manpages.

Comment: i have tried using strcat(). i used the statement- strcat(Dimen2[0],Dimen1). When i did that a blank space was concatenated to Dimen1 @cmaster

Comment: If there is a blank space after `strcat()` then there was a blank space before `strcat()`. Might have been invisible, but these functions never invent characters. So check your source strings. Printing with `printf("\"%s\"", Dimen2[0]);` might help debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#define MAX 32

main()
{
    char Dimen2[MAX][MAX] = {"blah","blah","blah"};
    char Dimen1[MAX*MAX] = ""; //initalise so safe to pass to strcat
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<MAX;i++)
    {
       strcat(Dimen1,Dimen2[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",Dimen1);
}
```